# Weird Issue With Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Issue:
First API calls only returns top 3 posts. 
The next_url returns no data(data array is empty and pagination string is null)
The 4th post is suspect because I am unable to get it with API calls and it is not returned in the first API call.

Details:

- Using v1/users/self/media/recent endpoint
- Using Javascript to loop through calls, using "next_url" for the 2nd and subsequent call.
- Using Access Token
- Worked fine(returned all posts) until "the 4th post" was made

Why do I think one specific post is the issue? Because I am unable to retrieve it using the API. If I set the max_id to this post id, then I get all other posts before this post.
If I leave max_id out, the first call gets all posts newer than this post.

Verified that I am not in a Sandbox.

Has anyone encountered this before?  and why would one post be breaking the next_url API call? Is there something in the post causing this?

I can't give out the IG account, sorry I know that would help, but it needs to remain private.

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer on a project that makes extensive use of the legacy Instagram API. It has, for a long while now, been extremely flakey. We have experienced your exact issue many times and there is no practical solution.

However, all Instagram APIs have now (finally!) been migrated to Facebook. You should use the new [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/) which will be properly supported going forward.